# Run cypress.io headless

Tags: testing, cypress

Is it possible to run cypress.io headless (without browser)? I got it to work locally, with browser, but my problem is that our build tool, Bamboo, can not run the exec file (?) to run it inside a browser. I tried something like `npx cypress run --headless`, but the time it took to run the test was super slow, and It also failed to visite web pages with this command: `cy.visit('http://www.google.com')`

Answer (score 4):

First of all I'd try to run Cypress headless locally to see if they run well.

But as you say, that is the way to run Cypress headlessly, passing on `--headless` parameter to the `run` command. It shouldn't change in any other way compared to using the headed mode, so make sure that that extra time is not due to other processes going on.

Also from Cypress `3.8.1` you can run headless Chrome `--headless -b chrome` so that's another way of testing it.

Comment: @RMT If this answer does not work, please add more information (logging from the build server)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried..
`npx cypress run --headless  --spec "cypress/integration/filename.spec.js"`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This documentation helped me [Cypress Error Messages](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#cy-failed-because-the-element-cannot-be-interacted-with). Check this out.